# Azure Active Directory copy data source connection with "SharePoint Online"

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-data-factory

I am connecting to a linked service to SharePoint Online using Azure Data Factory. I have admin access to everything on my site and in the Active Directory.

I have granted `Site.FullControl()` permission to my site in "App registration" and also granted in SharePoint site  but still it is showing me I don't know what else to do.

This is the error I get:

> Failed to get metadata of OData service, please check if service URL and credential is correct and your application has permission to the resource. Expected status code: 200, actual status code: Unauthorized, response is : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token type is not allowed."}.
> Activity ID: 4cc5411a-2932-40c9-baaa-c77a22f9270a.

Comment: Did you read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list#prerequisites?

Comment: @LeonYue Yeah, I did the same steps but that is still showing the same error and I am retrieving a list not a file